# C# Regex - if string only contains a character

Tags: c#, regex

Using C#/Regex, how do I find a string that only contains commas and no alphanumeric (or other non-comma) symbols?

```
a: ',,,,,,,'  match
b: ',,,,,,#A' no match
```

Answer (score 8):

```
[^,]
```

If that matches, that means a string contains a non-comma character.

A more complete example:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(yourTestString, "[^,]"))
{
    // This string does NOT contain commas
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
var text = ",,,";
Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^,+$");    // true
```

Answer (score 2):

If I read your question correctly, you want to know if a string contains only commas.

If so, use this regex: `^[,]+$`.

This will only match on strings that contain one or more commas and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

A string of only commas?

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^,*$");
```

That will tell you whether or not `str` consists entirely of commans or not.

Comment: `Regex.Match()` returns a `Match` object, so you'd have to check that object's `Success` property to find out if it worked.  If all you want is a yes-or-no answer, `IsMatch()` is more appropriate.

Comment: @Alan Thanks :) I updated my answer. (I don't know C#, just regex, but figured I could look up the C# syntax and answer anyways. I was close, right? haha)

Comment: I think the person who designed the Regex object was on drugs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that, as a one-char regex will always have to examine each character of its input string in the worst case, a simple for-loop will definitely be more efficient.  Something like this will give the exact same effect in less time and space than any equivalent `Regex`:

```
private void IsOnlyOneChar(string input, char c)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
        if (input[i] != c)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Not literally the answer you were looking for, but in my opinion this is your optimal solution.